# How to get bootstrap tabs to show up on the bottom of the left or right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to make bootstrap tabs show up on the BOTTOM LEFT and/or BOTTOM RIGHT hand side.  I cannot find any information on the net describing how to do this.  The closest I've found shows tabs to the left and right, but at the top of the side, not the bottom.

Here's the code I have thus far:

```
<div id="tabHeaderId01" class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul id="tabListId" class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
    <li id="tabid_One" class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li id="tabid_Two"><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
    <li id="tabid_Twee"><a href="#twee" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabContentsId01" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">
    Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
   Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="two">
    Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
   Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="twee">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
   Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
  .tabs-right-align
  {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0;
    /* prevent floated child bug */
  }
  .tabs-right-align>li 
  {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    float: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

/* custom inclusion of right, left and below tabs */

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs
{
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
.tab-content
{
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 4px 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 4px 4px;
          border-radius: 0px 0 4px 4px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  border-color: transparent #ddd #ddd #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
  *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 19px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  *border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have a bootply demo with what happens now:

http://www.bootply.com/p5Z5uc6Gwb

I'm having TWO issues:

1. I cannot get the tabs to show up at the bottom of the left side.  When I try to do a 'navbar-right' obviously this will not work.  But there is no 'navbar-bottom', so how do I get the tabs to show up at the bottom of the left side?
2. I need to be able to have a border for the content that encapsulates it.  However, when I set a border to the tab-contents, it sticks a border around EVERYTHING, including the tabs.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `float:left` to `width:100px` on line number 89 of your css.
2. Replace `border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;` with `border:1px solid #ddd;` on line number 109 of your css.
3. If you want your tab content on the right side then add below css

   ```
   .tab-content
   {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 10px;
   }
   ```

**Also theres are lot of unneccessay css code.**

heres bootply with your css
http://www.bootply.com/RgdCqhNWSv

heres bootply without unneccessay css code.
http://www.bootply.com/TYLrCsfBH2

Comment: Thanks for the response but that doesn't work (as you can see if you click on the 'run code snippet'.   First, the content shows up at the top and it needs to be to the right of the tabs,  Second, it doesn't show up at the bottom of the left hand-side.  It looks like it is on the top of the left-hand side.  This is exactly what happens to me.

Comment: I don't want you to think I don't appreciate your help.  I do!  But also when I change the width of the tab-contents, the contents show up on the left, not on the right side.  It's my bad. I should have shown an example that was not 100% width.

Comment: And I ran your changes in bootply, since the snippet here does not include bootstrap.  If you do that also, you will see how your code is not working.  I really WANT it to work, because I also need to be able to switch the tabs from the left side to the right side (on the bottom), and your code involves fewer changes than others.

Comment: And yes, I had seen that 'fix'.  I did not use that because it involved too much hardcoding of widths, as opposed to using other css to get things to line up.  There's actually a better example on github, but it doesn't address tabs on the left-side bottom and right-side bottom...

Comment: Please ignore the 3rd comment.  I posted it in the wrong place!

Comment: you wanted the "tabs" on the "left/right at Bottom" right?, so the snippet does what you ask view it in full-screen. or are confusing "tabs" with "tabs-content"? your question states that you wanted the "tabs" to show on the bottom, aligned on left/right. are you talking about "tabs" or "tab-content"?

Comment: have edited the answer and provided with bootply snippet links, i hope it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some research and this trick https://cleansupersites.com/bootstrap-left-side-tabs/, i found this solution that may be useful to you.

I forked and modified your bootply there, working for tabs left and right : http://www.bootply.com/O7jv2YhMBn

Here is the full snippet on Bootstrap 3.3.7

```css
/* tabs top, right-align */

  .tabs-right-align
  {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0;
    /* prevent floated child bug */
  }
  .tabs-right-align>li 
  {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    float: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

/* custom inclusion of right, left and below tabs */

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs
{
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
.tab-content
{
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
  min-height: 122px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 4px 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 4px 4px;
          border-radius: 0px 0 4px 4px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  border-color: transparent #ddd #ddd #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
  *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 19px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  *border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
#tabListId {
  width: 150px;
}
.tabs-left .tab-content {
  margin-left: 149px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.tabs-right .tab-content {
  margin-right: 149px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Tabs left</h2>
  <div id="tabHeaderId01" class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul id="tabListId" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="tabid_One" class="active"><a href="#lone" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li id="tabid_Two"><a href="#ltwo" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
    <li id="tabid_Twee"><a href="#ltwee" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabContentsId01" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="lone">
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ltwo">
      Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ltwee">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Tabs right</h2>
  <div id="tabHeaderId01" class="tabbable tabs-right">
  <ul id="tabListId" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="tabid_One" class="active"><a href="#rone" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li id="tabid_Two"><a href="#rtwo" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
    <li id="tabid_Twee"><a href="#rtwee" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabContentsId01" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="rone">
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.<br>
      Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="rtwo">
      Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor rsit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="rtwee">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Are you saying that I need to make ALL of those changes to the css, or just the 3 changes you specify with comments?

Comment: Also, I need to have the tabs also show up on the bottom of the RIGHT HAND side.  Is that possible with your code?  Do I just move the content to the bottom for that?

Comment: I don't want you to think I don't appreciate your help. I do! But also when I change the width of the tab-contents, the contents show up on the left, not on the right side. It's my bad. I should have shown an example that was not 100% width.

Comment: And I ran your changes in bootply, since the snippet here does not include bootstrap. If you do that also, you will see how your code is not working. I really WANT it to work, because I also need to be able to switch the tabs from the left side to the right side (on the bottom), and your code involves fewer changes than others.

Comment: Hello aaava, I added snippet to my original answer with both examples of tabs left and right.

Comment: HI. sorry, I have migraines and sometimes am unable to respond.  That's great, but again, the tabs are on the top.  I am trying to get the tabs on the bottom of the left and right hand sides.  Probably too late for you to see this, and sorry about that...